# How can I represent this automorphism of Q(i,a)?

Tags: functions, pattern-matching, replacement

Let $a$ represent some real irrational number.
I am trying to perform computations with an automorphism $f:\mathbb{Q}(i,a)\to\mathbb{Q}(i,a)$ which fixes $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ pointwise and maps $a$ to $i a$.

What's the best way to represent $f$?

My approach below didn't work, since `f@f` performs a replacement on the symbol `f`:

```
f[x_] := x /. a -> I a
f[a]

(* I a *)

f@f[a]

(* -a *)

(f@f)[a]

(* I a (* Not the same as f@f[a] ?! *) *)
```

What's the best way to define `f` so that this does not happen?

Comment: Look at result of f@f. MM is doing exactly what you ask it to.

Comment: Thanks, I see now. How can I represent my automorphism f?

Comment: What is $\mathbb Q(i,a)$?

Comment: The smallest field containing the rationals, i, and a. We can think of an element of $\mathbb{Q}(i,a)$ as a complex polynomial in a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `f` to operate on `f` however you would like:

```
ClearAll[f]

f@f := f@f@# &;

f[x_] := x /. a -> I a

{f[a], f@f[a], (f@f)[a]}
```

> ```
> {I a, -a, -a}
> ```

However if you expect this to extend to e.g. `(f@f@f)[a]` you may want something like:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[f] = Superscript[f, 2];
f[Superscript[f, n_]] := Superscript[f, n + 1]
Superscript[f, n_][x_] := Nest[f, x, n]
f[x_] := x /. a -> I a
```

Now:

```
(f@f@f)[a]
```

> ```
> -I a
> ```

Comment: One can also use `\[CircleDot] = Composition` for example.

Comment: @Kuba I'm afraid I don't understand what you're implying; could you give an example?  Also, at least in v7, `\[CircleDot] = Composition` is not valid syntax, but I assume you meant `CircleDot = Composition`.

Comment: Oh, yes, I don't know why I've written this :) ofc `CircleDot` :)